# Disallow tag duplicates from my code

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I have a form input and list of tags. If you click on a tag from the list it will be added to the input's value. This is working OK. But...

Now, if I click twice on a tag - it is added two times to the input. I want to check for duplicates, if tag is found in the input don't add it but remove it from the input if its link is clicked again.

Also, if there's no such a tag in the input, don't highlight it as well.

I'm pretty sure I should get the current value of the input and search in it for duplicates but... I tried to use indexOf and it didn't worked at all.

```
// clear input on start
$('#form_tags').val( '' );

// add a tag when clicked
$('#add-tag > a').on( 'click', function( event ) {
  add_tag( $(this).data( 'slug' ) )
  $(this).css( 'background-color', '#e0e0e0' )
  event.preventDefault()
})

function add_tag( tag ) {
  // input element
  var input = $('#form_tags');
  // current input value
  var curr = input.val();

  // --- duplicate or not? add or remove? ---

  // update the value of the input
  input.val( curr + tag + ', ' )
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6be5ab0/).

Comment: I don't understand, neither your code snippet nor the JSFiddle show your use of `indexOf`. The answer could use `indexOf` so to remove what you tried with nothing but a "it didn't work" left me more confused.

Comment: I tried `if (curr.indexOf(tag) >= 0)`

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/q6be5ab0/2/

Comment: @Ananth Thanks! Why not answer? :)

Comment: Need you really this ugly commas at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update your fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6be5ab0/1/) with other `add_tag` function:

```
  var tags = [];
  function add_tag( tag ) {
      if (~tags.indexOf(tag)) return;
      tags.push(tag);
      var input = $('#form_tags');
      input.val( tags.join(', '));
  }
```

And for remove, when clicked twice: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6be5ab0/3/)

```
  var tags = [];
  function add_tag( tag ) {
     var i = tags.indexOf(tag);
      if (~i) {
        tags.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
       tags.push(tag);
      }
    $('#form_tags').val( tags.join(', '));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is `~` doing? ;O

Comment: it's binary inverting. if argument is `-1` only, this get us 0(false).

Comment: You can check it as `i != -1` or `i >= 0` also

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of tags:

```
// clear input on start
$('#form_tags').val( '' );
var tags = [];

// add a tag when clicked
$('#add-tag > a').on( 'click', function( event ) {
  add_tag( $(this).data( 'slug' ) )
  $(this).css( 'background-color', '#e0e0e0' )
  event.preventDefault()
})

function add_tag(tag) {
    if (tags.indexOf(tag) > -1) {
        tags.push(tag);
        updateTags();
    }
}

function updateTags() {
    $('#form_tags').val(tags.join(', '));
}
```